# What's the best way to say "don't reinvent the wheel"?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas

In [this answer on SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75589/4171), I mentioned "não reiventar a roda"-- in an attempt to say, "don't reinvent the wheel". Is this the right "translation" for this idiom? The idiom, for better or worse, means:

Do not make/create/invent something from scratch that has already been made/created/invented -- use what is already there!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression ***"reinventar a roda"*** is in fact the correct translation for "reinvent the wheel", and is of common usage at least in Brazil. [This Wikipedia article](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventar_a_roda) (in Portuguese) have more information about this expression.

Note however that when using in the imperative form, you should use *"reinvente"* instead of *"reinventar"*. Examples:

> Não reinvente a roda!
>
> Em geral, não é bom reinventar a roda.

Your usage in that SOpt answer is correct in this regard BTW, although I'd use *"não tent**e** reinventar a roda"* (implicit *"você"*) or *"não tent**es** reinventar a roda"* (implicit *"tu"*).

Comment: Also this: _"...ou seja não tent**e** criar tudo do zero, mas sim, us**e** um framework que já resolveu todos esses problemas."_

Comment: Também usamos em Portugal.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!